# Is there a standard place to put my Aliases? bashhrc vs. bash_aliases

Tags: alias, bashrc, .bash-profile, bash-alias

Is there a standard place to put custom aliases?

If not, what are the benefits and disadvantages of `.bash_aliases`, `.bashhrc`, and `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Well, I can add that I've been using custom aliases in `.bashrc` and they seem to be universally available in all interactive shell sessions.

Answer (score 0):

A login shell would read .bash_profile and an interactive shell would read .bashrc. So, aliases would be used in an interactive shell thus put into .bashrc or a separate dot file such as .bash_aliases and sourced from .bashrc. Read the bash manual under the heading INVOCATION.